# Parallelization for loop

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a list like that;

```
HOSTLISTS = [
            {
        "name":"like1",
        "ip": "192.192.192.192",
        "token":"aaaa",
            },
            {
        "name":"like2",
        "ip": "193.193.193.193",
        "token":"bbb"
            },
            {
        "name":"like3",
        "ip": "194.194.194.194",
        "token":"ccc"
            },
```

And I have a function like that;

```
def function1(_ip, _name, _token):
```

I want to run them in parallel in a for loop. (Or it can be multithreading, I want it to work independently of each other.)
I tried using joblib;

```
Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(function1)(_ip, _name, _token) for x in xxx for y in yyy)
```

Here the code didn't work as I couldn't complete the for loops(for x in xxx for y in yyy).
I need your support to fix it with different suggestion or again using parallells.

Thanks.

Comment: let's assume you aren't calling it in parallel, how is your function called in a single core to begin with ? and what does your function do ? you might end up with a code that's working slower than on a single core if you just slap parallel on your code without giving it some thought.

Comment: a trivial answer is to wrap your function in another function that accepts a single input only which you can simply parallelize out of the box, but this won't really mean your code will get any faster, unless your code is embarrassingly parallel, which is not always the case.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you're asking. Are you struggling to provide the `_ip`, `_name` and `_token` arguments to the function? Or are you having a more specific issue with `joblib` and its classes? Give a traceback of the issue you're having, and perhaps un-obfuscate the `for` loop you're writing (so we can see where the argument variables come from).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run two function in parallel

```
from multiprocessing import Process
p1=Process(function1(_ip, _name, _token))
p2=Process(function2(_ip, _name, _token))
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

update

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def run_parallel():
    pool = Pool(processes=len(HOSTLISTS))
    # now it will pass the dict inside the list to your function
    # insted of using function1(_ip,_name_token) use
    # function1(host) and reference ip and other attributes like this host.ip
    pool.map(function1,HOSTLISTS)

run_parallel()
```

Comment: This is ok, but I want to run the same function (just function1) in parallel in a loop.

Comment: @snorlax ok add this inside a loop then change function2 to function1 and try it

Comment: @snorlax or create a Pool with numbers of elements in HOSTLISTS and map the function to the list